# Transmission-daemon error permission denied

Tags: debian, permissions, transmission

I have set up transmission-daemon on a bananapro to be a torrent server. I have created a directory for it in the root home folder and given `chmod 777` permissions to this directory so that anyone can write there, but no luck with this. Any ideas on what can be wrong? I tried googling it, tried some things, but they didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: By 'the root home folder', do you mean `/root`? If so, you probably shouldn't put it there; root is for systems administration, and services have their own areas.

Comment: yeah, exactly that one. i dont have any other users there, so that is the easiest way for me to store those files

Comment: `/root` often doesn't have a+x permission, which means that no matter what the permissions are on a directory under it, average users can't use it. This is for a good reason. You should make a user to run transmission as, then store the data somewhere under `/home` or `/var`.

Comment: You might be right, maybe keeping it in `/root` directory is not the best idea. I will try to move it somewhere else and check if it works. Anyway, what can I do, to let other programs write into `/root`?

Comment: You would have to do `chmod a+x /root`, but this is not a good idea security-wise. `/root` and the root user are meant for systems administration; you shouldn't have ordinary operations running with those permissions. And if `/root` can be seen or modified, it increases attack surface available to a (hypothetical) hostile user on the system.

Comment: I have created a directory outside of `/root` and it works just fine now. The problem I get now is the download speeds to the bananapro are much lower than to my pc. My internet is 125down/20up, and on pc I get about 10-12MB/s. This happens both when I download stuff to my class 10 card and a hdd connected with sata.